# Select a two-word field name in mySQL, called from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

trying to get information from a field and it's not recognizing the field name.

```
$selectsecurityname = mysql_query("SELECT security name FROM securityinfo") or die(mysql_error());
```

Have a feeling it's because the fields name "security name" is two words. Is there a way to pass a two-word field name, or do I have to change everything to omit spaces?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use backquotes around non-conformant field names:

```
`security name`
```

And in the future, only use conformant field names.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with backticks (key next to the left of the "1" ):

```
$selectsecurityname = mysql_query("SELECT `security name` FROM securityinfo") or die(mysql_error());
```